# Best Data Type for a blog article in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, types

Currently I'm making a blog software. One problem is that, what data type to use to store the blog articles in SQL Server. I can use `varchar(MAX)`. But the length of each of the articles is unrestricted. So, there may be performance problem as SQL Server uses paging of 8k. One way out, I thought that I can make multiple database entries for a single blog article. But there is another problem to `select` and `update` (I think update will be a big problem with multiple entries.)
Can you make a suggestion regarding the schema of a blog article in Database?
Thanks in advance.
I'm using SQL Server 2008, Standard Edition currently.

Comment: what's wrong with using varchar(max)?

Answer (score 7):

Use varchar(max), if the data exceeds 8KB SQL Server will use over-flow pages, a pointer will be used on the original page in that case

Comment: +1 - Let SQL worry about the page usage for something like this.  It's not like you'll be doing a lot of high-speed processing of blog data in this scenario.

Comment: I agree totally with you of using `varchar(MAX)`. In the current scenario it's probably a better solution. But we can try to find a more better solution. Thanks for your patience.